# How to test React.js component appearance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, galen

I need to test my component's styles one by one separatly from each other.

I've looked into the [Galen framework](http://galenframework.com/) which is suitable for that because I can describe the outlook and I thought to render React components to the real DOM layout and then give it to the test framework, but as I understood it can't test given DOM layout, only by URL's.

Maybe you have some experience in testing the GUI of React.js applications?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is using and recommending the **[Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html) test framework together with [React's TestUtils](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html)**. So far, this has worked fairly well for me.

It allows you to write unit tests for React components in a similar way as for other JavaScript modules.

From their Jest intro:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import CheckboxWithLabel from '../CheckboxWithLabel';

describe('CheckboxWithLabel', () => {

  it('changes the text after click', () => {
    // Render a checkbox with label in the document
    const checkbox = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" />
    );

    const checkboxNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(checkbox);

    // Verify that it's Off by default
    expect(checkboxNode.textContent).toEqual('Off');

    // Simulate a click and verify that it is now On
    TestUtils.Simulate.change(
      TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(checkbox, 'input')
    );
    expect(checkboxNode.textContent).toEqual('On');
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks for replay, maybe I didn't express it clear in the question but I asked about testing outlook. I mean I need to test i.e. that elements in my component don't overlap each other or that text wraps correctly and doesn't go under some element. I have to test styles but not behaviour

Answer (score 1):

component based tests are currently not possible, because integration with other JavaScript framework is currently not implemented. But you can use Galen for a integration/E2E test